# Getting error with ajax form submit when using OOP in PHP and Sweet Alert confirm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to submit a form with ajax jQuery and I want sweet alert before submitting form with confirmation.

The form is working fine when I am not using any AJAX or any JavaScript but I want to submit form without reloading the page and I want an alert to appear before clicking the *submit* and *cancel* buttons with the Sweet alert method (i.e. `swal()`).

This is my HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="myform"  class="countrysaveform" action="include/db_connect/actions.php" method= "POST" >
<div class="form-body">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Cournty Name</label>
<input type="text" name = "country" id="country" class="form-control"  placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name= "userip" id= "userip" class="form-control" value="<?php $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; echo $ip; ?>" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Status</label>
<select name ="status" id= "status" class="form-control">
<option value="active">Active</option>
<option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" name="save" id="save"  class="btn blue">SAVE</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn default">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is my *class.php*:

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';

    //echo $current_timestamp;

    class db_class extends db_connect{

        public function __construct(){
            $this->connect();

        }

        public function create($country, $status, $ip ){

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `ux_country` (`country_name`, `country_status`,`added_by_ip`,`added_date`,`added_on_time` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, now(), now() )") or die($this->conn->error);
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $country, $status, $ip);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $stmt->close();
                $this->conn->close();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

And this is my *Connection.php*:

```
  <?php
        define('db_host', 'localhost');
        define('db_user', 'root');
        define('db_pass', '');
        define('db_name', 'uniquesolutions');

        class db_connect{
            public $host = db_host;
            public $user = db_user;
            public $pass = db_pass;
            public $dbname = db_name;
            public $conn;
            public $error;

            public function connect(){
                $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
                if(!$this->conn){
                    $this->error = "Fatal Error: Can't connect to database" . $this->connect->connect_error();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

And this is my *action.php* where I am calling this to store in database.

```
 require_once 'class.php';

    if(ISSET($_POST['save'])){
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $status  = $_POST['status'];
        $ip = $_POST['userip'];
        //$current_timestamp = date();
        $conn = new db_class();
        $conn->create($country, $status, $ip);
        header('location:../../Country_View.php');
    }
```

This is MySQL database structure:

```
TABLE `ux_country` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `country_status` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `added_date` date NOT NULL,
  `added_on_time` time NOT NULL,
  `added_by_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this is sweet alert code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myform').on('submit',function(e) {  //Don't foget to change the id form
  $.ajax({
      url:'include/db_connect/actions.php', //===PHP file name====
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      type:'POST',
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //Success Message == 'Title', 'Message body', Last one leave as it is
        swal("¡Success!", "Message sent!", "success");
      },
      error:function(data){
        //Error Message == 'Title', 'Message body', Last one leave as it is
        swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong :(", "error");
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //This is to Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"
  });
});
```

Comment: So if I understand, you just want to alert BEFORE submitting the form?  Why can't you just move the `swal()` method before your ajax call (ie,pull it out of your callback methods)?   What am I missing?

Comment: @SarfarazDalawi I see you commented below: "_when I am clicking SAVE button it is showing success message but not storing in db and I think it is not calling to that actions.php file_". Please see my updated answer where I address the PHP code (i.e. _action.php_) towards the end.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML Change

```
type="submit"
```

to

```
type="button"
```

in Javascript: 
change

```
$('#save').on('submit'....
```

to :

```
$('#save').on('click',function(e) {  //Don't foget to change the id form
      alert('Submitting form');
      $.ajax({
         ......
```

For getting alert on click of Cancel button, add id to your cancel button:

```
<button type="button"  class="btn default" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
$('#cancelBtn').on('click', function(){
   alert('sweet message');
   $("#myform").trigger('reset');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting but my code is now like this, but when I am clicking SAVE button it is showing success message but not storing in db and I think it is not calling to that actions.php file.. please help

Answer (score 0):

> I want to submit form without reloading the page and I want alert before submitting submit and cancel button with Sweet alert method.

One way to achieve this is to use an *Event delegate* for any button click. For this, change the click handler from:

```
$('#myform').on('submit',function(e) {  //Don't foget to change the id form
```

To:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
```

Then the call to [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) can be executed whenever a button is clicked. This can be achieved by checking the [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of the event target.

```
if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON') {
    e.preventDefault(); //This is to Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"
}
```

This can also be achieved using jQuery's [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method and [event.stopPropogation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
var target = $(e.target);
if (target.is('BUTTON')) {
    e.stopPropogation();
}
```

Then add an *id* attribute to the button labeled **cancel**.

```
<button type="button" class="btn default" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

After that, the *id* attribute can be checked in the click handler using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
if (target.attr('id') == 'save') {
    swal('save clicked');
    //trigger AJAX request
}
else if (target.attr('id') == 'cancel') {
    swal("cancel button clicked");
}
```

Then when serializing the form for the *data* option of the call to $.ajax(), use the *id* attribute to select the form:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'include/db_connect/actions.php', //===PHP file name====
  data:$('#myform').serialize(),
```

Consequently, [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) won't include the `<button>`s in the data, since those aren't really form elements. So in the PHP code (i.e. *action.php*), check for the name of one of the inputs (e.g. *country*) to determine if data should be saved:

```
if(isset($_POST["country"])){
```

And at the end of that php code, it doesn't really make sense to call [header()](http://php.net/header) to redirect to a different location, since this code is called asynchronously (i.e. via AJAX) and redirects (i.e. response codes 3xx) aren't followed. Typically in an asynchronous call a string or JSON data is returned.

Putting this altogether, we have this code below. See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0pzw-ajd5).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.is('BUTTON')) {
      e.preventDefault(); //This is to Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"
    }
    if (target.attr('id') == 'save') {
      swal('save clicked');
      //trigger AJAX request
    } else if (target.attr('id') == 'cancel') {
      swal("cancel button clicked");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="myform" class="countrysaveform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Cournty Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="slobovia">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Status</label>
      <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
<option value="active">Active</option>
<option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn blue">SAVE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn default" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```